# Custom SnakeYAML dump styles

Tags: java, yaml

I want to make custom dump styles in different cases, for example I have that sample code:

```
DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
options.setDefaultScalarStyle(DumperOptions.ScalarStyle.PLAIN);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options);
Map<Object, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("list", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("entry1", "entry2")));
map.put("multiline", "line 1\nline 2\nline 3");
map.put("oneline", "line");
map.put("oneline-special", "line with #");
map.put("oneline-special #", "line with #");
yaml.dump(map, fileWriter);
```

Dump result is:

```
list:
- entry1
- entry2
multiline: |-
  line 1
  line 2
  line 3
oneline: line
oneline-special: 'line with #'
'oneline-special #': 'line with #'
```

Problem:
I want to have double quoted value in any case, if it's a string `key: "value"`, and if only needed for key, then: `"key": "value"`. Also I need to save `DumperOptions.ScalarStyle.PLAIN` in order to support pretty style multiline strings output.
I tried to find anything related to that, found few info about `Representer` extending, but seems it cannot solve my problem with explicit style (no quotes on key, but double on value), I thought about extending `Emitter`, but it's final class so I can't use it without rewriting part of library. 

So, my final result should be:

```
list:
- "entry1"
- "entry2"
multiline: |-
  line 1
  line 2
  line 3
oneline: "line"
oneline-special: "line with #"
"oneline-special #": "line with #"
number: 512
```

Any solutions? Need your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As no another solution was provided, I solved it by directly changing `processScalar()` method in `Emitter` class. First added check to force double quoting if scalar is not a key and not a multiline (because I wanna plain style for multiline):

```
if (!simpleKeyContext && !analysis.multiline) {
    style = ScalarStyle.DOUBLE_QUOTED;
}
```

Then changed switch case logic, where in case of `SINGLE_QUOTED` `ScalarStyle` we write as double, so, if needed, the key will be written in double quoted style.

Runned JUnit tests with simple key value and different styles, multiline case and list case. All is right and shine.